# Seeing 'redirect_url' errors when using the LiveSDKs

Tags: android, ios, authentication, onedrive

When setting up the example Android application, I updated the configuration file to include my application id that I received when I registered on the [development portal](https://account.live.com/developers/applications/index).  Then when attempting to sign in to the application on my device I see this error message:

> The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The client application must be marked as 'mobile', or the value must be an absolute URL which matches the registered redirect URI.

What do I do to get around this error so that I can sign in with the sample app?

Answer (score 1):

This error is correctable by adding a Redirect Urls setting in the [Microsoft Account Developer Center](https://account.live.com/developers/applications/index), as pictured below.

[image: Image of Developer Center settings with Redirect Url highlighted]